# Sublime text won't open error to parse settings:unexpected trailing characters in packages

Tags: sublimetext3

Sublime text is not opening. I keep getting this error:

[image]

When I click <kbd>OK</kbd> nothing happens, and when I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> and take away sublime this message comes up again.

I haven’t found a solution on the internet that works. 
I cannot find preferences or sublime-settings in the packages.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're seeing isn't offering to help you solve the problem, it's telling you where the problem exists. Thus clicking `OK` dismisses the dialog but leaves the problem behind, so it recurs when you restart Sublime.

In order to fix the problem you need to fix the file that it's telling you about. The `Packages` folder can be found by using `Preferences > Browse Packages` if you're on Windows or Linux or `Sublime Text > Preferences > Browse Packages` if you're on MacOS.

---

#### EDIT

Note that the folder that this opens ***is not*** the folder that Sublime Text is installed into (which also happens to contain a folder named `Packages`). That folder contains only `sublime-package` files that ship with Sublime to provide default functionality.

The location that this opens is a folder named `Packages` that is either stored somewhere in your home directory (which is platform specific) or, in the specific case of the Portable Version of Sublime Text, a folder inside of the portable install (but still not the `Packages` in the top level).

This command exists because the folder that Sublime uses is generally hidden from casual observation by your operating system, making it harder to find if you don't know where to look.

---

From there you can enter the package that's causing the problem (`User)` and open the file with the issue (`Preferences.sublime-settings`) in order to fix it.

The two numbers displayed at the end of the file name (`12:1`) tell you the line and column where the error was found, so you can focus your attention on the correct place. The error in question will be somewhere in the vicinity of that location.

In this particular case since the problem is in your user preferences file, you can just select `Preferences > Settings` (as above, `Preferences` is under `Sublime Text` if you're on MacOS) to have Sublime open the file for you; your file is on the right hand side of the split window that opens.

The error message `Unexpected Trailing Characters` is a hint that the problem is that there is something other than space/tab characters following the final `}` character in the file; whatever those are, if you remove them the problem should go away.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/a2c05067bbc0229b25a4b1bdb20f12c7. You mean package here? I can't open sublime text at all. and inside the package i don't find the file user. https://gyazo.com/d6831216f913f13d5d0334a540c7da38

To be more clear i get this message before i even open sublime text. So i cant use settings that are found inside sublime text

When i search preference in my searchbar all i see is  preference.dat that's empty.

Comment: Your image shows the installation folder for Sublime. That's not the folder that you get taken to if you use the menu command I mention in my answer.

Comment: Awesome i got it to work now. Thank you. Now i got this error 
https://gyazo.com/2a33910e182b5febdf67e7f2ccf062cb

It work's now i can open the sublime text to get away from this error i tried using [] and everything turns read

Comment: The solution to that the same as above; open the appropriate file and fix it. There's something wrong at line 3, column 1. Based on the error, the file contains more than just `[]`. You can remove the file entirely to stop the error (but you will lose whatever key bindings you might have applied in there).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the starting `{` and ending curly braces `}`

See: [preferences_settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8NSA.png)

Answer (score 0):

On my machine the location of these files is:

```
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User
```

Obviously, change `myusername` to your user name in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I quote @still_breathing. In my case I had created a wrong configuration in the preferences. That was preventing Sublime Text from opening.
I navigated to
C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User
and deleted my configurations from the file
'Default (Windows) sublime-keymap.

Sublime immediately opened up.